# Cookie Set and Redirect? If you click Button A - this happens, Button B - this happens

Tags: javascript, php, web, cookies

Our church has two campuses. I want to make a drop-down or lightbox selection that allows them to select "South Campus" or "Downtown Campus" as their main church location. They would see the selection option when they visit fbcjax.com. If they choose south, I want it to set a cookie to redirect fbcjax.com ALWAYS (until cookies cleared)to fbcjax.com/south. If downtown is selected, I wan't a cookie set to not show the selection option again (until cookies cleared).

How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1):

You would have to use cookies, then you could use pretty much most server-side languages or javascript to redirect the user.  Hard to provide anything else without knowing what you're working with and/or what your language preference is.